# Encoding DXV in ffmpeg (resolume codec)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I do have it listed in `ffmpeg -codecs`, but it returns `Unknown encoder 'dxv'`.

Do I have to reinstall ffmpeg with DXV dependencies? If so, how? Why is it listed in -codecs if it's unknown?

I've found this on the web:

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/dxv_8c_source.html

Supposedly the source for dxv encondig. Should I use it anyhow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the output of `ffmpeg -codecs`,

`D.VIL. dxv                  Resolume DXV`

FFmpeg can only decode DXV, not encode it. The 2nd character would be `E` instead of `.` if an encoder were available. You can also check `ffmpeg -encoders` to see a list of only encoders.

Comment: ouch, so there's its no way to encode DXV in ffmpeg? damn...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like the Resolume team are [not interested](http://resolume.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11351&p=45680&hilit=ffmpeg#p45846) in open-sourcing the DXV codec so that programs like `ffmpeg` can encode videos to that format.

My preferred alternative at the moment is [Resolume Alley](https://resolume.com/download/). It actually works really well.

There are other options that they recommend in [their manual](https://resolume.com/manual/en/r4/dxv).